# How to manage queue message processing

Tags: azure, system-design

I've got service A communicating with service B thru a Queue.

The message contains information that requires service B to reach out to a DB and run a query, before storing it in another DB.

Service B won't be returning anything, and is async to Service A.

The thing, is that service A is sending over the messages in a loop, which is triggering 429 errors from service B.

What's the best way to manage this kind of situation?

If it helps, both services are Azure functions and I'm using Azure's standard Storage Queue.

TIA!

Comment: Refer the Azure Storage queue [limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/scalability-targets). Is your service B is implemented as a queue trigger function? how many queue messages are you generating per minute? how long does each execution of service B take?

Answer (score 0):

429 is usually related to Rate Limit. You're either adding too many messages at once or the SDK to add a message to a queue is failing somehow.

You can fix in a few ways:

1-Implement a retry policy

2-Add a 'sleep' every x seconds

3-Add less messages in a chunk